# Angularjs focus unexpectedly requires an async setTimeout to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok StackOverflow, riddle me this.

I have a button that I click on which toggles the visibility of an input. In the scope function which changes the visibility I use javascript to set focus on that input tag. What I want to know is why does it not work unless I wrap it in a `setTimeout`?

```
$scope.toggle = function() {
  if ($scope.hideInput) {
    setTimout(function(){
      input.focus();
    }, 0);  // That's right, zero!
  }
  $scope.hideInput = !scope.hideInput;
};
```

Here's a working jsfiddle with a button that correctly sets the focus and a button that doesn't:

http://jsfiddle.net/PsS99/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can tell you the reason why.

First you can't focus element, with css `display:none`.

So in the one (broken) method, you focus the element before it is actually displayed.
Because the angular will go line to line and `$scope.hideInput = !scope.hideInput;` will trigger the watcher for a `digest`-loop. In that loop your input will be set to `display: block`.

The timeout will move the focus command into it's own thread, and the `$scope.hideInput = !scope.hideInput;` will trigger the `digest`, too. 
But the `digest` is curiously fast enought to display the element before the `input.focus();` will be executed.

This is my explanation but understanding this, did help me in some curious problems of angular's timing.

Maybe use this ? http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-focus-on

A directive to set the focus by variable.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I'd like to know if I'm guaranteed to have this work deterministically or if I've just introduced a race condition into my code.